# Get the property of an object in an array by checking another property of that object

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my JSON from an API:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "location": "Random",
            "hostname": "hostname1",
            "port_range": "20001 - 37960"
        },        
{
            "location": "Germany",
            "hostname": "hostname2",
            "port_range": "21201 - 21299"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write a function which will return the associated `hostname` when I pass the `location` as parameter.

For example, if I enter `Germany` I will get "hostname2" as a string.
If I enter `Random`, I will get "hostname1" as a string.

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: var host = obj.data.find(x => x.location == input.value).hostname;

Comment: Use the title to communicate the specifics of your question, not "Hey, I have a question." We get that. You're on Stack Overflow, a site that is entirely about asking questions.